# Change X Axis using PHP data

Tags: charts, highcharts

I am using using Highcharts to show some charts. I want to change the X Axis points with data from MYSQL. I have 4 columns in my MYSQL server: ampere, Voltage, Temperature and seconds. I want to change the X AXis by using the seconds-column. The other works fine when I implement the data from MySQL like so:

```
series: [{
                name: 'Ampere',
                data: [<?php echo join($Ampere_array, ',') ?>]
            }, {
                name: 'Voltage',
                data: [<?php echo join($Voltage_array, ',') ?>]
            }, {
                name: 'Temperatuur',
                data: [<?php echo join($Temperatuur_array, ',') ?>]
            }]
```

How can I change the X Axis? I tried using the same method as the other 3 MYSQL data. BTW I am using a basic area chart.

The X Axis should return the seconds of the type double, but the code returns nothing.

```
xAxis: {
                allowDecimals: true,
                categories: {
                    [<?php echo join($Seconden_array, ',') ?>]
                    },
                    style: {
                      color: 'white'
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Honestly it is not clear for me, so what is your goal, what it is and what should be?

Comment: I want to change the values of the X AXIS based on MYSQL data.

Comment: But your poitns are returner in the pairs : [x,y], or other? You can use xAxis options, or its not enough?

Comment: I've updated the code a bit.. But it returns nothing @SebastianBochan

Comment: The categories should be and array not object as you have

Comment: $Seconden_array is an Array based on mysql_data

Comment: But it should be categories:[] not categories: {}